# C delete node in a linked list

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

I have this program which has a function to create a list, to delete a node if its value is equal to the parameter `x` of the function `delete_node()` and then it print the linked list nodes. Creation and print work fine but I can not delete the node with the value `x`. I get either my original list or a blank list.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct list {
    int value;
    struct list *next;
};

struct list *create_list(struct list *l, int x) {

    //allocate memory for new tmp node
    struct list *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    tmp->value = x;

    //tmp shtohet ne koke te listes
    tmp->next = l;

    //l behet koka e listes
    l = tmp;

    return l;
}

struct list *delete_node(struct list *l, int x) {

    while (l) {
        if (l->value == x) {
            //printf("%d", x);
            struct list *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct list));

            tmp->value = l->next->value;
            tmp->next = l->next->next;
            l = tmp;

            printf("%d ", tmp->value);

        }

        l = l->next;
    }

    return l;
}

int main() {

    struct list *l = NULL;

    for (int i = 5; i > -6; --i)
        l = create_list(l, i);

    l = delete_node(l, 3);

    while (l) {
        printf("%d ", l->value);
        l = l->next;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are traversing the linked list until you reach the end, hence `return l` will return NULL when `x` is not found anywhere in the list. When `x` is found, you are tossing away the original record and returning a copy of the  next record ending up tossing 2 records, then you continue to traverse the rest of the list ending up returning NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fix to your problematic code.

```
struct list *delete_node(struct list *l, int x) {
    struct list *prev, *retval=l;
    while (l) {
        if(l->value == x) {
            if(l==retval) {
                retval=l->next;
                free(l);
                l=retval;
            } else {
                prev->next=l->next;
                free(l);
                l=prev;
            }
        }
        prev = l;
        l = l->next;
    }

    return retval;
}
```

You don't need to allocate more memory to discard unwanted node. You are severely leaking memory by doing so.

You need to keep track of the head of your list. This is what retval is for. You will return the same head if `x` is not found or found in non-head node. You will return the next node if `x` is found in the head node.

You also need to keep track of the previous node to be able to tell the previous node the the current node will be freed. This is necessary for singly link list.

Answer (score 1):

The key to deletion is keeping track of the previous mode.

By staring with a "fake" head node, the `while` loop is simplified.

```
  struct list *delete_node(struct list *l, int x) {
    struct list start;  // Code only uses the next field
    start.next = l;
    struct list *p = &start;
    while (p->next) {
      struct list *q = p->next;
      if (q->value == x) {
        p->next = q->next;
        free(q);
        break;
        }
      p->next = q;
    }
    return start.next;
  }
```